# code is strangely asynchronous

Tags: android, asynchronous, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem where i call a method on a line and on the next line i call another method that need the previous method completed, but is not what is happening and im getting a NPE;

This is my line, it starts when i long click on a list

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int pos,
        long arg3) {

    String nick = ((UserList) adapter.getAdapter()).getLista().get(pos)
            .getNick();

    if (activity.service.getConversa(nick) == null) {
        activity.service.addPVTConversa(nick); //need this completed
    } 
        activity.selectTab(nick); //to call this

    return true;
}
```

Then i go to addPVTConversa():

```
public void addPVTConversa(String target) {
    pvts.add(new Conversa(this, target));
    Intent it = new Intent(MyService.ACTION_NEW_PVT);
    it.putExtra(MyService.EXTRA_NICK, target);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyService.this).sendBroadcast(it);
}
```

And then to the receiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String target = intent.getStringExtra(MyService.EXTRA_NICK);
        addPVTTab(target);

    }
```

**And here is my problem:** I need the method selectTab() be called after addPVTTab() cause the selectTab() are looking for a tab that were not created yet. All the code runs on main thread but selectTab() is called before addPVTTab(). What should i do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected with `sendBroadcast()/onReceive()`. You should call `selectTab()` in your `receiver.onReceive()` instead.

Comment: It will complicate my life a bit but if theres not other way i'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use an interface to pass the message that there was a new tab added. That would be a synchronous call.